# show that three points are collinear

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $AB \neq AC$. Point $E$ is such that
$AE = BE$ and $BE \perp BC$. Point $F$ is such that $AF = CF$ and
$CF \perp BC$. Let $D$ be the point on line $BC$ such that
$AD$ is tangent to the circumcircle of triangle $ABC$. Prove that
$D,E,F$ are collinear.[image]

Comment: Please show your efforts on the question and where you're stuck.

Comment: The first condition is odd as the question's tag reads **Euclidean** geometry...

Comment: @DonAntonio What's odd about it?

Comment: @Wojowu That, as far as I know, Euclides calls "triangle" to the usual figure without same sides, meaning: degenerate triangles don't exist in euclidean geometry. That's all.

Comment: @DonAntonio The first statement is not about the triangle being nondegenerate, it's about it being nonisosceles...

Comment: @Wojowu Hehehe...thank you! I read something completely different. You're right, of course. +1

Answer (score 1):

Let $EK \perp AB$ at $K$ on $AB$, $AH \perp BC$ at $H$ on $BC$.
$\triangle EBK \sim \triangle ABH \Rightarrow$
$$
\frac{EB}{AB}=\frac{BK}{AH}=\frac{AB}{2AH}
$$
Similarly
$$
\frac{FC}{AC}=\frac{AC}{2AH}
$$
From which it follows:
$$
\frac{EB}{FC}=\left(\frac{AB}{AC}\right)^2
$$
On the other hand, $\triangle ADB \sim \triangle ADC$, we have
$$
\frac{DB}{AD}=\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{AD}{DC}\Rightarrow \frac{DB}{DC}=\left(\frac{AB}{AC}\right)^2
$$
Therefore, $\frac{EB}{FC}=\frac{DB}{DC} \Rightarrow D,E,F $ are collinear.